# i cant split xml data in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

i am trying to split an xml file

this is my xml which creates automatically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <S:Body>
        <ns2:genelSorguResponse xmlns:ns2="http://genel.service.ws.epvys.g222.tubitak.gov.tr/">
          <return>
            <PetrolPiyasasiIllereGoreAkaryakitFiyatlariResult>
              <PetrolPiyasasiIllereGoreAkaryakitFiyatlari>
                <Tarih>2018-04-28 00:00:00.0</Tarih>
                <YakitTipi>Kurşunsuz Benzin 95 Oktan</YakitTipi>
                <Il>İSTANBUL (AVRUPA)</Il>
                <FirmaMarkasi>7KITA</FirmaMarkasi>
                <Fiyat>0.0</Fiyat>
              </PetrolPiyasasiIllereGoreAkaryakitFiyatlari>
            </PetrolPiyasasiIllereGoreAkaryakitFiyatlariResult>
          </return>
         </ns2:genelSorguResponse xmlns:ns2="http://genel.service.ws.epvys.g222.tubitak.gov.tr/">
      </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

and this is my code:

```
dim dosyaAdi = "yakit_" & now.day & "." & now.month & "." & now.year & ".xml"
 Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
    Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
    Dim m_node As XmlNode

    m_xmld = New XmlDocument()

    m_xmld.Load("C:\Milenyum\yakitkontrol\" & dosyaAdi)

    m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("return/PetrolPiyasasiIllereGoreAkaryakitFiyatlariResult/PetrolPiyasasiIllereGoreAkaryakitFiyatlari")

    For Each m_node In m_nodelist

      Dim FirmaMarkasi = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(3).InnerText

      Dim YakitTipi = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText

      Dim fiyat = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(4).InnerText


      if FirmaMarkasi = "OPET" and YakitTipi="Motorin" then
      sonucTutar = fiyat.toString.replace(".", ",")
      end if

    Next
```

with that code i can not access the data i want.

but when i delete these codes from xml file:

```
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <S:Body>
            <ns2:genelSorguResponse xmlns:ns2="http://genel.service.ws.epvys.g222.tubitak.gov.tr/">
</ns2:genelSorguResponse xmlns:ns2="http://genel.service.ws.epvys.g222.tubitak.gov.tr/">
      </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

i can acces any data i want. but xml file creates automatically so i need to edit xml file every time. is there any other way? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("//return/PetrolPiyasasiIllereGoreAkaryakitFiyatlariResult/PetrolPiyasasiIllereGoreAkaryakitFiyatlari")
```

that was my solution. thanks anyway